Spring JPA Repository Left Outer Join
Hello I am trying to develop a solution using JPA Repositories to force a left outer join instead of an inner join.  I am trying to do a query essentially to get all items in Table1 even if the join returns a null in table 2.  When doing a basic CrudRepository call findAll, the inner join is used instead of the left join.  Please note, I am only using this for view purposes only so I am thinking a unidirectional is ok. Any suggestions on how to use a left join to do this?
@Entity(name="Table1")
public class Table1 {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int Id;

    @Column
    private String tableName;
    
    @Column
    private Timestamp createTS;

    @Column
    private Timestamp updateTS;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name ="table1Name" referencename="tableName")
    private List<Table2> t2;

@Entity(name="Table2")
public class Table2 {
   @Id
   @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "increment")
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int Id;

   @Column
   private String table1Name;
   
   @Column
   private String attribute1;

   @Column
   private String attribute2;



You can write an HQL query for this.  In fact, this is probably the standard way to go when the factory methods don't work the way you want.

Yea I was hoping not to do this.  It would make looping through some of the data so much easier than that.

You may view the JPA repo methods as a friendly suggestion for how to achieve something.  In the event that they can't deliver, then resort to HQL or maybe even raw SQL.
